# counting records in unix file

Tags: unix

This was an interview question, nevertheless still a programming question.

I have a unix file with two columns name and score. I need to display count of all the scores.

like

jhon 100
dan 200
rob 100
mike 100

the output should be

100 3
200 1

You only need to use built in unix utility to solve it, so i am assuming using shell scripts . or reg ex. or unix commands

I understand looping would be one way to do. store all the values u have already seen and then grep every record for unseen values. any other efficient way of doing it

Comment: So your question is? What language/environment/tool? I'd use `awk`.

Comment: @thomas yes, i guess so,

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
cut -d ' ' -f 2 < /tmp/foo | sort -n | uniq -c \
    | (while read n v ; do printf "%s %s\n" "$v" "$n" ; done)
```

The initial `cut` could be replaced with another `while read` loop, which would be more resilient to input file format variations (extra whitespace). If some of the names consist in several words, simple field extraction will not work as easily, but `sed` can do it.

Otherwise, use your favorite programming language. Perl would probably shine. It is not difficult either in Java or even in C or Forth.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat foo.txt 
jhon 100
dan 200
rob 100
mike 100
$ awk '{print $2}' foo.txt  | sort | uniq -c
      3 100
      1 200
```

Its a pity you can't do a count with sort or uniq alone.

Edit: I just noticed I have the count in front ... to get it exactly the same you can do:

```
$ awk '{print $2}' foo.txt  | sort | uniq -c | awk '{ print $2 " " $1 }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very complicated in perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

my %count = ();

while (<>) {
        chomp;
        my ($name, $score) = split(/ /);
        $count{$score}++;
}

foreach my $key (sort keys %count) {
        print "$key ", $count{$key}, "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could go with awk:

```
awk '/.*/ { a[$2] = a[$2] + 1; } END { for (x in a) { print x, " ", a[x] } }' record_file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively with shell commands:

```
for i in `awk '{print $2}' inputfile | sort -u`
do
    echo -n "$i "
    grep $i inputfile | wc -l
done
```

The first awk command will give a list of all the different scores (e.g. 100 and 200) which then
the for loop iterates over, counting up each separately. Not very super efficient, but simple. If the file is not to big is should not be a too big problem.